# I'm stuck on the desktop. No taskbar and no shortcut key for restart

Tags: .desktop, desktop-icons

Help! I'm stuck on the desktop. No taskbar for restart. Cannot do the shortcut key either. Earlier, I removed and reinstalled `python3`. Then a notice came saying something about changes and update (I assume because what I do on python3). Then I shut down my laptop, booted again and here I am stuck.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what OS/release you are using, however Ubuntu tools are very reliant on `python3` so removing them will stop any tool or function that requires it from working.  Please provide OS & release details (inc. if desktop, server or other).   Can you login to a text terminal?  If so can you provide your actual command history (the last few commands where you removed & re-installed; if you did it via command), but OS & release details first.

Comment: FYI:  SysRq keys to reboot, turn off or all other functions will still work as they go straight from the keyboard to the kernel bypassing any GUI or shell. If they aren't working you usually have a kernel panic; you seem to be describing only user shell & GUI functions lost because of loss of required python3.

Comment: I have ubuntu 16.04 LTS. No, i can't access terminal with Ctrl+Alt+Tab. Just now i force shutdown with power button but i still facing same problem

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 should switch to the text screen (if F1 doesn't work, try F2, F3 and so on). You should be able to login to text mode session from there and get the comand history @guiverc mentioned.

Comment: Hey i can acces this Ctrl+Alt+F1. What should i do, how do i get command history?

Comment: login using the text terminal, the command `history` will show your command history (we're not interested in all commands, just the few commands related to this issue, at least starting with the package removal and everything after that). You won't know the sysrq keys, so search online "magic sysrq" & wikipedia entry is good & normally near top of search, if you want to know about those. Logs will be found in `/var/log/apt/history.log` as well (packages removed; added etc), but ensure you have `python3-minimal` installed (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python3-minimal)

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your responses. To resolve the issue i installed apt ubuntu-desktop, and my computer work again, no files deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe seems similar to the [issue](https://linuxnatives.net/2015/fixing-black-screen-after-login-in-ubuntu-14-04) answered in this article.

Try the following:
Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to open a text console and login using your username and password and run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

It will reconfigure all unpacked but unconfigured packages and then upgrade all installed packages where available.